# Problem with import and using SwingFXUtils in gradle project

Tags: gradle, javafx, build.gradle, java-module, module-info

I'm very new to gradle and javaFx.
I'm working on a gradle project (not mine) and I need to import SwingFXUtils to make some operations.
Importing it into the java file:

`import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;`

cause the error: "Cannot resolve symbold SwingFXUtils".

I tried to add it to java-modules.java file

`requires javafx.embed.swing;`
but it is not recognized and I'm having the error message: "Module not found:javafx.embed.swing"

then, I updated my build.gradle for the missing module: like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.19.0'
    id 'com.google.osdetector' version '1.6.2'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "libs"
    }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.geotoolkit.org/" }
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {

    toolName = 'my project'
    toolVersion = '1.0.0'
    mainModuleName = 'com.myproject'
    mainClassName = 'com.myproject.DcTool'
    jfxVersion = '14.0.1'
    pdfboxVersion = '2.0.27'
    platform = osdetector.os == 'osx'?'mac':osdetector.os =='windows'?'win':osdetector.os

    fixWayland = platform == 'mac' ? '' : platform == 'win' ? '' : '-Djdk.gtk.version=2'
}

version = "$toolVersion"

// Project dependencies.
dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains:annotations:19.0.0"

    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:$jfxVersion:$platform"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:$jfxVersion:$platform"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$jfxVersion:$platform"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$jfxVersion:$platform"

    implementation "com.fazecast:jSerialComm:2.6.2"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha4"
    implementation "de.skuzzle:semantic-version:2.1.0"

    implementation "info.picocli:picocli:4.3.2"
    annotationProcessor "info.picocli:picocli-codegen:4.3.2"

    implementation "org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:${pdfboxVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.pdfbox:preflight:${pdfboxVersion}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.jr:jackson-jr-objects:2.11.0"
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-swing', version: '11-ea+24'
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}

application {
    mainModule.set("$mainModuleName")
    mainClass.set("$mainClassName")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
    "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
    ]
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
       doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"

    options.javaModuleVersion.set("$toolVersion")
    options.javaModuleMainClass.set("$mainClassName")
}

run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
                "--module-path", classpath.asPath,
                '--patch-module', "$mainModuleName=" + files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir).asPath,
                "--module", "$mainModuleName/$mainClassName"
        ]
        jvmArgs += application.applicationDefaultJvmArgs
        classpath = files()
    }
    doLast {
        args = []
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': "$mainClassName"
        )
    }
}
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
jlink {
    moduleName.set("$mainModuleName")
    mainClass.set("$mainClassName")

    addOptions(
            '--bind-services',
            '--no-header-files',
            '--no-man-pages',
            '--strip-debug',
            '--compress', '2')

    launcher {
        name = "$toolName"
        jvmArgs += application.applicationDefaultJvmArgs
    }
}
```

I also tried to download jars of SwingFx and add them in a "libs" folder into the project but I have no result and compiler doesn't find modules I need.

What can I do to make it find this module?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You declare your other JavaFX dependencies as: `implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:$jfxVersion:$platform"`, so declare your `javafx-swing` dependencies the same way.  I don't think that is your core issue, and I'm not sure why there is a `platform` specifier here, because the platform can be determined from the build automatically.

Comment: Maybe try manually [resynching the gradle config and your IDE project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project).  The link is for Idea, use whatever method is required for your chosen IDE.  Again I don't know if this is your actual issue.

Comment: "I also tried to download jars of SwingFx and add them in a "libs" folder into the project", don't do that, fix the Gradle setup instead.  If you get stuck contact whoever created the project originally and ask their assistance.

Comment: @jewelsea Maybe something has changed, but the platform/classifier is not automatically determined in base Gradle. That sort of thing is done by the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin (using `osdetector` behind the scenes, or at least it used to). Without that plugin (and declaring the JavaFX dependencies in its own provided way), it doesn't grab the correct JavaFX artifacts. It looks like whoever wrote the above build script wrote their own less-sophisticated version of `org.openjfx.javafxplugin`.

Comment: (perhaps it was before the plugin existed, or they didn't want to pull in another plugin--the plugin at least used to have some rough edges against Gradle's native Java 9 module handling, when that was finally added).

Comment: @Denis Put `implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-swing:$jfxVersion:$platform"` with the other JavaFX dependency declarations (and get rid of the version you added). Your current attempt is likely downloading an empty JAR artifact (which exists for reasons beyond the scope of this comment).

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the info, maybe I was just mistaken in my assumption of how JavaFX works with Gradle builds.  For Maven builds I know the platform classifier is not needed for most builds, regardless of whether the Maven JavaFX plugin is used.  From your description I guess Gradle builds may be different in this respect.

Comment: @Slaw, jewelsea Thank you guys for your trying helping me.
I tried to insert the "implementation" row you suggested. I also added to my module-info.java a "requires javafx.swing", refreshed gradle but I'm still having error from compiler. It seems to not recognize swing libraries. In fact, the "import javafx.embed.swing;" gives an error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'swing'" and also the code: "SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);" gives error like:"Cannot resolve symbol 'SwingFXUtils'". Actually, the row in module-info.java forswing now has been recognized respect before
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why the module would be recognized but not the class inside the module. Are you using Gradle to compile the project (or, more specifically, do you have your IDE configured to delegate to Gradle)? In other words, does `./gradlew compileJava` give you the compilation error?